# Which one sounds more natural? "The most of them" or "most of them"?

Tags: definite-articles

> I used to have a lot of games and **the most of them** were untranslated
>
> I used to have a lot of games and **most of them** were untranslated

Comment: The second one. _Most_ with _the_ is part of the superlative construction, so it tends to be avoided elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The Second One. The first one is wrong, let alone natural.

Comment: Hi Khalid, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - e.g., by explaining *why* #1 is wrong, ideally backed up by reference to an authoritative source. For further guidance, see [answer].  :-)